# Select an option from drop down list using RJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rjs

Using RJS:

`page[:greeting].replace_html 'Hello World!'` replaces the text in the 'greeting' field with 'Hello World'.

I have a drop down list and would like to select an option with a specific id using rjs.

My question how do I select an option from a drop down list with id "sub_book" using rjs.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I used:

`page["sub_book"].selectedIndex = 5` //in this case am selecting the option with  id 5

Hope it might be of help to somebody else

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<select id="sub_book">
  <option value="1">First</option>
  <option value="2">Second</option>
  <option value="3">Third</option>
  <option value="4">Fourth</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sub_book").val(3);
});
</script>
```